# The Output page(Response page) of my Application, will given by JSP only.... Then what is the use of GWT at client side

Tags: gwt

I want to develop a Web Application by combining Spring Framework, GWT, Servlets, JSP........

I plan to develop Server side using Spring,Servlet ,JSP....

And for Client side, GWT....

The Output page(Response page) of my Application, will given by JSP only....
Then what is the use of GWT at client side....

please clear my doubt....

Answer (score 1):

Read the following

1) AJAX - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)

2) RIA - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Internet_application

3) GWT - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Web_Toolkit

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using purely jsp to create a web application is that each user interaction typically requires the entire page to be reloaded. Depending on what you're doing this approach is considered outdated. GWT is built on top of javascript and xhttp requests, allowing user interactions to affect only relevant portions of the page. This generally results in a faster and smoother user experience.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already decided that you want to use JSP, then you don't need GWT. Although you could use it to create custom dynamic components and embed them on your page. Or to create a part of your application where you find JSP not sufficient (which would be probably a part that should be more 'dynamic' and would require a lot of javascript).

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/overview.html#how